The Css units x y coordinate of interact.js don't match the pdf-lib units
I'm still working on a web app project to add signatures to PDFs
for the backend I use pdf-lib
for the frontend I use pdf.js by mozilla to display the pdf, and interact.js to move the signature image
I have a problem with the pdf-lib coordinates in placing the signature image in the pdf
I have read several issues and already know that x y in pdf-lib uses 1\72 inch units
then I tried using 1/72 inch units in the CSS in interact.js
but when I use it in pdf-lib, the units in the css don't match the units in pdf-lib
any ideas?
